# Install a package that is only one Python file and has no setup.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

How can i install a python package that does **not** have a `setup.py` file to call. I want to install a package that it happens to be only a `.py`.

Do i just save it as a `.py` and put it somewhere in the directory and then import it?

For example the [zipfile package](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/zipfile.py) and the [ElementTree XML parser](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/xml/etree/ElementTree.py)

P.S.: I have Python-3.x

Comment: Python 3 *comes with both those modules already*. You don't need to install those. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html and https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html. Do *not* install the Python 2 versions into Python 3.

Comment: Thank you on that tip! Are there editions existant for those two modules for Python 3?

Comment: Yes, and they are *already included*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** As said in the comments, these packages come with Python 3 so you should not install them manually (and certainly not the 2.7 versions). I let my answer bellow for people wanting to install custom package.

On a python interpreter, if you run:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
```

You will see a list of folder where your python executable search for module. You can put your file either in the `site-packages` folder or the `lib` folder.

Comment: Nice Mr Holt i will test now!

Comment: Can i please ask if those two packages are suitable for Python 3.x?

Comment: The packages may contain lot of compatibilities errors with python 3.0. As Martijn said in comment, these packages come with python 3 so you don't need (and you should not) install them manually.

Comment: You have untied my hands you people. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Just put the file somewhere in PYTHONPATH.

Comment: On the `PYTHONPATH` of the `Path` environmental variable?

Comment: Doesn't it have to be on the `C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages` file ?

Comment: A `site-packages` directory is in Windows PATH, so you can put the file right there.